# Use Variable in SQL Command SSIS of ADO net source

Tags: ssis

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community edition. I was trying to configure and ADO Net Source using SQL Command. However, I need to pass parameters to it. Is there an easy way to inject SSIS Variables into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, using expression.
Open data flow task, right-click on empty space there and choose "Properties".
[image]

In "Properties" window choose "Expressions"
[image]

In opened window choose [Your data source].[SqlCommand] and add you variable there in Expression input.
[image]

Comment: Make sure you set DelayValidation = True when you use expressions. This tells the program that properties are being set during run time.